# can plovr build tool use an external closure compiler?

Tags: java, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, plovr

The closure compiler in `plovr.jar` is older than the latest closure compiler.

Is it possible to use the latest closure compiler jar ball with plovr?

Comment: Looking at the [plovr source code](https://github.com/bolinfest/plovr), it appears that the closure compiler code is actually compiled with `plovr`. This makes me think that the easiest way to include the latest version of the closure compiler would be to update the closure compiler code and build `plovr` yourself. It is possible that plovr has customized the closure compiler code, so keep that in mind if something doesn't work right.

Answer (score 0):

@burnttoat11's comment is correct.

For ease of use, Plovr bundles the compiler code.

> The plovr repository includes branches which are copies of the Closure Library, Closure Compiler, and Closure Templates source code, so building plovr is entirely self-contained

To use a different version of the compiler, you'll have to checkout Plovr, update the Closure code, and compile it yourself.

It would be nice (but is not currently done) if:

- Plovr used Maven, the the Compiler now does

or

- Plovr allowed specifying an external Compiler jar, much as can be done with extern files.

Comment: What is the reason the plovr compiler*.jar is not updated? Or is it?